# How to determine camera angle in shader?

Tags: shader, godot

I'm using godot. My 3d game supports 4 camera angles and I'd like to use a different texture on my mesh depending on which angle I'm looking at.

The reason for this is that I'm creating the illusion of 2d by projecting 2d drawings over 3d objects and I need a different hand-drawn projection for each angle.

Maybe I can just look at CAMERA_MATRIX? I'm not sure how that changes as I rotate the camera...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `NORMAL` function.

The `NORMAL` function gives you the the surface normal relative to the camera witch is what I think you need.

EXAMPLE:

```
shader_type spatial;

uniform sampler2D colorGrad;

void fragment()
{
    ALBEDO = texture(colorGrad, vec2(NORMAL.x , 0)).rgb;
}
```

Comment: I think something like this could work, but you might also need: `render_mode world_vertex_coords;` to ensure that `NORMAL` is different depending on the camera location.